# Rendering haml partials takes a long time... why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, view, haml

My Rails 3.0 app on ruby 1.8.7 contains Haml 3.1.3. Most of the views are haml templates, it takes about 0.5-5ms to render them on my machine in production mode.

Having said that, a few partials take much longer. 300ms to 900ms for 30-60 lines of haml. It must be something in the way how I use it, but how could I debug what's wrong? The benchmarks are consistent and reproducible.

I'm not sure about possible sources of the error:

- deep partial nesting? (3-5 levels)
- deep haml nesting? (4-8 levels)
- use of block helpers?
- lots of translations?
- using haml with formtastic 2.0?
- using form builders for nested forms?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, what do the slow partials look like?

Comment: Currently I'm looking into Formtastic 2.0.2 as a source for this problem. Ive filed a bug report on github: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/744

Comment: You haven't answered my question. And why do you think Formtastic is responsible?

Comment: I've found (through ruby-prof) `image_tag` and `form_for`  take a lot of time, and replacing them with HTML and `#{interpolation}` is much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a number of things inside Formtastic 2.0:

- Lots of object lookups, uncached
- Lots of translations, uncached
- Use of try…rescue blocks which slowed it down tremendously

Fixes have been added to Formtastic 2.1 and up, making it a lot faster. Kudos to [Sascha Konietzke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139733/sascha-konietzke) for providing patches.

Answer (score 1):

A more recent way to fix this is [Hamlit](https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit), a high-performance Haml implementation with some limitations by design for performance. It claims 8.24x speedup.

Also, not Haml-specific, but look at [multi-fetch gem](https://github.com/n8/multi_fetch_fragments) for lists.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning hamlit, which indeed is faster. In this particular case uncached translations have been causing this, but adding a little extra speed is nice nonetheless.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't heard of that before. Any info on how to make sure translations are being cached correctly? (I'm always up for anything to improve Rails rendering perf!)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's Garbage Collection.  See these posts:

http://www.williambharding.com/blog/uncategorized/rails-3-performance-abysmal-to-good-to-great/comment-page-1/

http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/rails3-unbearably-slow-view-rendering-use-ree-with-gc-tuning/

If you're using REE 1.8.7 (which also fixes a memory leak, so you should be) then [you can tune your GC settings](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_garbage_collector_and_object_space).  I just did this last week and our response time dropped by 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Put in `.bashrc`:

```
export RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS=1000000
export RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_INCREMENT=500000
export RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_GROWTH_FACTOR=1
export RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=50000000
```

Source, and restart server

```
$> source ~/.bashrc
$> rails s
```

Depending on what is your problem, this might make rendering your partials faster (in my case, average rendering time got x3 faster).

Comment: What OS/machine and Ruby runtime did you use these settings on?

Comment: @mahemoff this was a while ago, but I think a 2013-macbook pro with 16gb ram

Comment: Lol exactly same rig here :) Thanks.